# How to append row to Sheets API if it doesn't exists, otherwise update it

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

in JavaScript I am trying to use Google Sheets API.
What I am trying to do is to append a row if it doesn't already exists in the spreadsheets, but update it if it is duplicated.

My sheets :

| IDS | Status |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | Status1 |
| A2 | Status2 |

What I want to push is : `[A1, Status2];[A3, Status1]`

So in this case, A1 Status is gonna change, and A3 is added as a new row.

(I already get in the array I want to push the IDs with (and the Status in another way):

```js
const getIds = googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId,
        range: "'Sheet 1'!A3:A23",
        auth,
    });
```

Comment: In your tag, `javascript` is used. But, when I saw your showing script, I thought that your script might be Node.js. So, I cannot understand your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? And also, what is `getIds`?

Comment: @Tanaike sorry for the tag, i added it.
getIds is what I use to get the list of 20 IDs (first column)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you wanted to achieve your goal using googleapis for Node.js. For this, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Your "Sheet1" of Spreadsheet is in the table of your question.

  - In your script, you are using the range as `'Sheet 1'!A3:A23`. But, in your table, it seems that the data is shown from row 2.
- You have the input value like `[["A1", "Status2"], ["A3", "Status1"]]`.
- You want to update "Sheet1" using the input value. When your showing table and your input value are used, you want to achieve the following situation of "Sheet1".

  ```
    IDS  Status
    A1   Status2
    A2   Status2
    A3   Status1
  ```
- From your added tag, you want to achieve this using googleapis for Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values to the Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth }); // Please use your authorization.
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
const inputValues = [["A1", "Status2"], ["A3", "Status1"]]; // This is from your question.

sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({spreadsheetId, range: "'Sheet 1'!A2:B"},
  (err, { data: { values } }) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    const obj1 = inputValues.reduce((o, e) => ((o[e[0]] = e), o), {});
    const obj2 = values.reduce((o, e) => ((o[e[0]] = e), o), {});
    const res = [
      ...values.map((e) => obj1[e[0]] || e),
      ...inputValues.reduce((ar, e) => (obj2[e[0]] || ar.push(e), ar), []),
    ];
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(
      {
        spreadsheetId,
        range: "'Sheet 1'!A2",
        resource: { values: res },
        valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
      },
      (err, { data }) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(data);
        }
      }
    );
  }
);
```

- In this sample script, first, the values are retrieved from the columns "A" and "B" of "Sheet1". And, the retrieved values are updated using the input value. And, the updated values are put to "Sheet1".

#### Note:

- In your showing script, it seems that the sheet name is `Sheet 1` which is not `Sheet1`. So, please confirm your sheet name again.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)